# bootstrap-datepicker - Enabling only odd or even dates?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Stefan Petre's Bootstrap-Datepicker found at [Github](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/)

It has a property 'daysOfWeekDisabled' which allows me to disable specific days of the week, but I now need to enable only Odd or only Even dated days within the calendar.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this ? Google search and a search through the datepickers docs on Github Doc hasn't produced a solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/mw4kyc9p/1/

use [beforeShowDay](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#beforeshowday)

```
$('#date').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (Date) {
            var day = Date.getDate();
            //enable even
            if (day % 2 == 0) return true;
            //disable odd
            else return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just a quick additional comment...I didn't notice at first that this code only enables every second day, not each even or odd date...To correct this change var day = Date.getDay(); to var day = Date.getDate();